# autoComplete combo Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, xmlhttprequest, jquery-events

****error in autoComplete combo Box
I think it may gets  called after xmlHttprequest finishes
please provide me a solution near a code line this `$("#isUsedCombo").combobox`**
***You will find 'isUsedCombo' str variable*****

```
function editGov(govID){

    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
           var x1=xmlHttp.responseText.split(",");
           isUsed=x1[5]; // isUsed comboxBox Value
           var str="<table> <tr>  <td>English Name</td> <td><input type=text id=txtEnName"+x1[0]+" value=\""+x1[1]+"\"> </td> <td></td></tr>     <tr>  <td>Arabic Name</td> <td><input type=text id=txtArName"+x1[0]+" value=\""+x1[2]+"\"> </td> <td></td></tr>        <tr>  <td>EnShort Name</td> <td> <input type=text id=txtEnNameSt"+x1[0]+" value=\""+x1[3]+"\"> </td> <td></td></tr>      <tr>  <td>ArShort Name</td> <td> <input type=text id=txtArNameSt"+x1[0]+" value=\""+x1[4]+"\"> </td> <td></td></tr>      <tr>  <td>Is Used</td> <td>  <select> id=isUsedCombo> <option value=1> Once</option>  <option value=2> Multiple </option>  </select>  </td> <td> </td></tr>     <tr>  <td></td> <td> <button class=bttnGov onclick=updateGov("+x1[0]+")> Update</button> </td> <td> <button class=bttnGov onclick=updateGov('close')> Close</button> </td> </tr> </table>";      
           DiaLgFrm(str);
           
            $("#isUsedCombo").combobox({
             selected: function(event, ui) { 
                isUsed= ui.item.value;
              }
            }); 
        }
    }
    var URL = "Empty\\emptyGovt2.aspx?govID="+govID;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true);
    xmlHttp.send(); }
```

Comment: this code block didt work


$("#isUsedCombo").combobox({
             selected: function(event, ui) { 
                isUsed= ui.item.value;
              }
            });

Comment: i am asking for error message not the code :)

Comment: ther is no error msg on console scr

Comment: hw colud i run ths code after the request finshes.

the problem is 'isUsedCombo' is nt avaiable on page, wen combobox function gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a problem with your string

change this

```
 <select> id=isUsedCombo>
```

to

```
 <select id=isUsedCombo>
```

in `var str=`